# AWS Free Tier usage limit exhausted when used Gradle-Beanstalk plugin for spring boot app deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gradle, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS free tier, specifically AWS Elastic Beanstalk for my Java application deployment using gradle-beanstalk plugin. Internally it uses S3 for storing archives. I have deployed hardly 100 versions for my application, still the monthly limit for **2,000 Put, Copy, Post or List Requests of Amazon S3** is exhausted within nearly 10 days.

snippet from my build.gradle -

```
plugins {
        id "fi.evident.beanstalk" version "0.2.3"
}
...
beanstalk{
    profile = 'my-profile'
    s3Endpoint = "s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    beanstalkEndpoint = "elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    deployments{
        staging{

            file = tasks.jar
            application = 'test-app'
            environment = 'test-app-staging'
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Please guide me on how to optimize this.

Thanks!

Comment: That is charged at `$0.005 per 1000 requests`, so it is unlikely to cost you much money (maybe a few cents per month?).

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, I am also trying to figure out why is it making so many list/put requests to S3 and how to optimize these requests?

Comment: Having the exact same problem here. Spring boot app being deployed manually, so no Gradle involved in the process. Limit of 2000 free put/post requests exhausted within a couple of days. Can't track down who is doing those requests.